# Jquery: Remove value when submit button pressed if value is the same as when the page loaded

Tags: jquery, forms, input

How would I remove a field value for each input that has the same value when the submit button is pressed down as when the page loaded using Jquery.

**Example of logic:**
Set variable equal to each input value on load
On mousedown of the submit button remove the value if it still matches that variable.

Still new to jQuery, thanks for any help :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the goal of this? are you implementing a placeholder, then trying to remove it on submit?

Comment: Yup! Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Yes, make the background color of the input transparent, then float a label behind it with the placeholder text. Then, when the user begins to type in the input, hide the label or show it depending on whether or not it has a value using the keydown event and a short setTimeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method I would use is to set a custom HTML attribute, so for example:

```
<input name="foo" value="test" data-default="test" />
```

Then, when the user submits the form, we compare the value of the form, with the default value. If they are the same, then we reset it. So:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $(this).find('input').each(function() { 
            if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-default')) $(this).val('');
        });
    });
});
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Or remove the data attribute and use `this.defaultValue` in it's place in code

Comment: I didn't use this, though it gave me the right idea for how to implement, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add an onChange event to all your input fields to track what fields are modified.

Storing defaults in another attribute will increase pageload time and duplicate all your data. Maybe your data is substantial. If so, just watch for changes.

**Example:**

```
var untouched_fields = []
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#form input').each(function() { untouched_fields.push( $(this).attr("id") ) }
   $('#form input').on("change", function() { untouched_fields.remove( $(this).attr("id") ) })
})
```

..then on submit, read untouched_fields.

Answer (score 0):

First, if the browser supports placeholders, use them instead of your functionality. Next, if placeholders aren't supported, update the inputs accordingly initially, and then undo that change on submit.

**HTML**:

```
<input name="first-name" placeholder="First Name" />
```

**JavaScript**:

```
// before all of your code
jQuery.support.placeholder = (function(){
    var i = document.createElement('input');
    return 'placeholder' in i;
})();

// in document ready
if (!$.support.placeholder) {
    // update value of empty inputs to the value of the placeholder attribute if set.
    $("input[placeholder]").val(function(i,val) {
        return val == "" ? $(this).attr("placeholder") || "" : val;
    }).focus(function(){
        if (this.value == $(this).attr("placeholder")) {
            this.value = "";
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        if (this.value == "") {
            this.value = $(this).attr("placeholder");
        }
    });
}


$('form').submit(function() {
    if (!$.support.placeholder) {
        $("input[placeholder]",this).val(function(i,val) {
            return val == $(this).attr("placeholder") ? "" : val;
        });
    }
});
```

In my own code i would actually position a label behind the input and show/hide it instead of touching the input's value.